# What is the name of the citation format used in bibtex

Tags: formatting

Does anyone know when we do

```
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{Bibliography}


@article{,
author = "
fjournal = 
journal = 
month = 
number = 
pages = 
publisher = 
title = 
url = ,
volume = 
year = 
}
```

what is the name of the citation format? Example: APA, etc...

Comment: The name of the citation format is `plain`.

Comment: @Fran - This comment comes rather close to giving a circular answer to the OP's question. You may want to add an explanation of what the "plain" citation call-out style looks like or does.

Answer (score 1):

The `plain`, `abbrv`, and `unsrt` bibliography styles are examples of bibliography styles that generate *numeric* citation call-outs.

"APA" is an example of an authoryear citation call-out style.

Answer (score 0):

As long as you do not use packages like `natbib` to change your citation style or define custom citation styles with `biblatex`, the name of the citation style equals the name of the bibliography style, in your case `plain`.

Comment: Actually, even if `natbib` is loaded, `plain` will only ever generate numeric-style citation call-outs.

Comment: @Mico You're of course right, I wanted to express that the independent change of styles (citation/bibliography) is mostly done with another package.